# How to send PIL images from python to Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js

I'm working on a project with Node.js

I'm using python-shell to send data as Json format but can't send images as arrays in the json (too large)

How can I send PIL images from python to the Node server? what is the necessary code for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if on same machine, what about using files?

Comment: I already thought of that but it would consume memory if I have several images,I want to send the images directly from python to Node

Comment: why do you think files consume memory while networking/interprocess communication not?

Comment: Because I'll use file system to save images from python program and use the path to process these images in the Node.js program ,am I missing something?